# change font colour within php echo

Tags: php, fonts, echo

I have a html hyperlink within a php echo, this in itself has taken me a while to get working correctly, the code is below:

```
echo "Guidance on Organisational Context can be found".'<a href="http://www.website.com/page.html" target="_blank"> here</a>';
```

What I would like to do is change the text colour of the entire text, the examples i have found so far on google only change text of the hyperlink "here", otherwise i just dont know how to insert the additional html into the existing code, any suggetions would be greatly appreciated.

Also i would prefer #111111 style colour picker if possible

Comment: Extend your html with the `style` attribute like this: `<a href="#" style="color:#111111"></a>` or add a ` a{ color: #111111} ` to your css file.

Comment: yup, just tried that, echo "Guidance on Organisational Context can be found".'<a href="http://www.website.com/page.html" style="color:#f44242" target="_blank"> here</a>'; and all it did was change the hyperlink "here" to red, i want to change the whole line

Answer (score 0):

its ok i resolved this by adding two lines:

```
echo '<span style="color:#f44242;text-align:left;">Guidance on Organisational Context can be found</span>';
echo " ".'<a href="http://www.website.com/page.html" style="color:#f44242" target="_blank"> here</a>'."<BR>";
```